# facing issue to find xpath expression

Tags: xpath

My XPath `'//div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']'` is working fine, but after this tag there is `'#document'` text present and after this `'#document'` there is html tag, so when I extend the XPath expression as `'//div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']/#document/html'`, it is throwing exception as follows:

> Caused by: class org.jaxen.saxpath.XPathSyntaxException:
>   //div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']/#document:
>   70: Expected one of '.', '..', '@', '*', QName.

So please guide me how to write XPath for this.

Thanks,
Dhananjay

Comment: Maybe this is because they're separate documents (assuming XHTML `iframe` tag semantics), and XPath isn't cross-document?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, XPath does not descend into `iframe`s.You see, XPath expressions are tied to a particular XML document, such as an HTML document,<sup>1</sup> that they can be evaluated against. In the browser, an `iframe` counts as a separate document. The `<iframe>` node itself is a part of the parent document; but it is merely a pointer to another document (the `iframe`'s contents) which is completely separate.

That seems to be the gist of this [email chain](http://objectmix.com/javascript/344183-xpath-doesnt-seem-descend-into-iframes.html), and seems to fall naturally out of the fact that XPath expressions are evaluated by calling [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate) (that is, a member of a particular `document` object), as implemented in Firefox. This suggests that the overlap between the various specs defining `iframe`s and XPath excludes traversing that document boundary in a single XPath expression — or at least that seems to be Mozilla's interpretation.

But take note that all of this is an guesswork based on Firefox's particular implementation of the `XPath` specification. This limitation may or may not apply to other browsers, but I would suspect that it does.

It also seems to explain why Selenium requires you to switch context from one document (the parent HTML page) to another (the `iframe` itself) in order to execute XPath expressions against it, as hinted at by the solution posted by @singaravelan, [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816113/712526) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498605/712526).

---

<sup>1</sup>But only if the HTML document is magical enough! (Not all HTML documents are well-formed XML: browsers are much more lenient than XML parsers can be; Cf. @MathiasMüller's comment.)

Comment: "a particular XML document, such as an HTML document" - be careful with the wording, HTML is not necessarily well-formed XML. Apart from that, this answer is spot-on.

Comment: Oh, dear! The tyranny of malformed HTML! Well, the browser's idealized notion of an HTML document, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your source XML, but one thing we know for sure is that it doesn't contain an element called "#document", because that isn't a legal element name. For the same reason, you can't request an element called "#document" in your XPath expression.

Comment: Therefore (and it's just a guess based on the common case), you probably need just to delete the `#document` part to make the XPath work. If you want a more detailed explanation why, please show us the critial part of your XML so we can tell you what this `#document` text is.

Comment: @Michael Kay ,I have a html page within another html page.So I want to access element from inner html page.But it is not working.So I need to write xpath for this.And after this xpath '//div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']',my inner html page is starting with html tag.So I need something like '//div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']/html'.So please guide me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with different XPath to bypass the word: #document with the word: descendant
For example:

```
//div[@id='sharetools-container-div']/iframe[@id='sharetools-iframe']/descendant::*[1]
```

or something like that. It is depend on **what** do you want in the inner html.

Comment: Does this really work? In which browsers (or other XPath implementations) does this work? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First thanks to raise this question. I am also face the same problem. 
with help of following line I got solved for my case.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("fraToc")));
```

Thanks.

Comment: The OP's question has nothing to do with Selenium, which you do not mention; the only reason I understood what you were talking about is because I saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28816113/712526) earlier.