# Get iframe content by using Javascript XPATH in Javascript executor for selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying the following code to move to frame and then get the content but it is returning empty content document.

```
var iframe = document.evaluate('//iframe[contains(@src, \"//my.leadpages.net/forms/5620062778032128/5654100301578240/5645914630782976/html/?lp-in-iframe=1\")]',document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).contentDocument;alert(iframe);
```

Also if you can guide me through for how can I move to frame and then get it's contents via nodes.Iframe has no id,name etc so I have used xpath way.It is detecting the frame as resulting XpathResult but I am not sure how to move into it and then extract text for various nodes.This has to be in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you provided some html with the iframes but try the following code. It can be achieved with JAVA only, you don't need javascript for this.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("frame xpath expression here")));
//do your stuff here.
//to get the content of this frame, it depends on the structure of the html
//if content is within some div then simply do this.
//this would be the css selector for some DIV where the content is inside the iframe:     
//div#divContentID
WebElement divContent=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#divContentID"));
String content=divContent.getText();
//to switch out of the iframe back to the main content.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I hope it helps!!